# Case Insensitive PropertyName Evaluation in SLD

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, sld, geoserver-explorer

I have a table layer_styles created by **QGIS** and, inside this table, the column *stylesld*.

The problem is that the PropertyNames (column names) stored inside this column and the generated SLD that **geoserver explorer** creates (and sends to geoserver) are UPPERCASE too, but in postgis, the column names of tables are LOWERCASE.

Is there a way to transform the LOWERCASE/UPPERCASE in **column name**(PropertyName) inside SLD or use a case insensitive evaluation on **column name** (PropertyName) ?

For example:

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc=""http://www.opengis.net/ogc"">
  <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>
      <CaseInsensitive>TENSAO_OPE</CaseInsensitive>
    </ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>138 KV</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
```

*Note that **CaseInsensitive** tag is only an example to explain what I need.*

Answer (score 2):

Checking the [SLD cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions) you could try the function strToUpperCase:

```
<ogc:Function name="strToUpperCase">
    <ogc:PropertyName>TENSAO_OPE</ogc:PropertyName>
</ogc:Function>
```